# Magento Products cannot be saved

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I'm trying to add new product in my Magento theme, but it cannot be added
the button (save) that add the product doesn't work.

this problem appeared suddenly although my website was running without any problem

Comment: see in console if there is any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you filled out any information needed in the Tabs on the left side. They are red marked.

Did you miss the "Prices Tab" with "Price" and "Tax-Class"?

Comment: I filled all required fields

Comment: Enable Logging, Check System.log, Check Web-inspector from Browser. Upload all Magento Datas. Maybe some are missing when uploading the Magento.